# Java Row Set / Data Access Object Failure

Tags: java, jdbc, selenium, data-access-layer, resultset

I use a Row Set to pass query results in my selenium framework. Occasionally the data access object throws the following

**java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYDatabasename:1433/DB**

It uses this same driver and rowset to access and only fails occasionally. Any help would be appreciated.

RowSet:

```
public static RowSet GetRowSet(String SqlQuery, String[] Parameters, String DB){

    CachedRowSet rs;
    String ROWSET_IMPL_CLASS = "com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl";
    rs = null;

    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(ROWSET_IMPL_CLASS);
        rs = (CachedRowSet) c.newInstance();

        rs.setUrl(Configuration.DBConnString + DB);
        rs.setUsername(Configuration.DBUser );
        rs.setPassword(Configuration.DBPwd );
        rs.setReadOnly(true);
        rs.setCommand(SqlQuery);

        for (int    p=0; 
                    p<Parameters.length; 
                    p++)

        { 
            rs.setString(p+1, Parameters[p]);   
        }

        rs.execute();
```

Example of code:

```
public void examplevoid(String string, String string2)

throws Exception {

    RowSet RoS = null;  
    RoS = Example.GetExample(string, string2);
    while (RoS.next()) {
        String Example = RoS.getString("Example");
        selenium.click(Example)
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad(setup.timeoutsetting);
    }
    RoS.close();
```

Which uses and in turn calls the rowset:

```
  public static RowSet GetExample(String string, String string2) throws 
  String[] Parameters = {string, string2};
  RowSet ExampleRowSet= null;
  ExampleRowSet = DataAccess.GetRowSet("Some SQL HERE", Parameters,  Configuration.DB); 

return Example;
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems impossible. Either the driver class is loaded, or it isn't. Once loaded, successive calls to `DriverManager.getConnection()` with the same JDBC URL should never give that error. What else is going on?

**Edit:** The only questionable thing I see is that all of your Configuration.* properties appear to be fields in a class somewhere. If some of those properties are changing values between tests, maybe your JDBC driver is causing that exception to be thrown because of a bad property value, like the `Configuration.DB` or `Configuration.DBConnString`. If it's fairly repeatable, try changing

```
rs.setUrl(Configuration.DBConnString + DB);
```

to

```
String url = Configuration.DBConnString + DB;
log.debug("Using JDBC URL: " + url);
rs.setUrl(url);
```

When the exception happens, see if the string looks different.

Comment: still encountering the same problem. Here is some more information from the error trace.

`at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)`

`at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)`

`at com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetReader.connect(Unknown Source)`

`at com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetReader.readData(Unknown Source)`

`at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.execute(Unknown Source)`

`at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.execute(Unknown Source)`
`at com.DataServices.DataAccess.GetRowSet(DataAccess.java:144)`